# listing the number of local variables only linux

Tags: linux, shell

So I'm trying to only list the local variables on my shell using the **set**
command in a script file, however this command when I store in it a variable to call also lists the environmental variables as well so I was wondering how could I list only the local variables? Anyway I could subtract the number of local variables from the number of environmental variables using the **printenv** command?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Other than the fact that environment variables are inherited by child processes, there's no difference.

Comment: I actually just found out if I store the number of local variables in another variable and subtract it from the number of environmental variables in another stored variable and can then store that number in once again another variable  I was just curious to see how it could be done